# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, redis

So I am having a redis **Set** operation everything is working fine but when `IDatabase dbConnection = redisConnection.GetDatabase();` of code is running then it is throwing error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=StackExchange.Redis
  StackTrace:
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase(Int32 db, Object asyncState) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1420
   at RedisCache.CacheExtensions.SetRecord(String recordId, String data, Int32 minute) in RedisCache\CacheExtensions.cs:line 11
   at BusinessLogic.Services.Order.WebOrderService.SetOnlineOrderRedisCount(WebOrderGroup webOrderGroup) in BusinessLogic\Services\Order\WebOrderService.cs:line 2770
   at BusinessLogic.Services.Order.WebOrderService.SaveToMainTable(CurrentUserDetailedDTO currentUser, IUnitOfWork uow, AppClientIncomingJsonRequest jsonRequest, WebOrderGroup webOrderGroup) in BusinessLogic\Services\Order\WebOrderService.cs:line 2752
   at WebOrderService.ProcessOrder(WebOrderGroupDTO dto, CurrentUserDetailedDTO currentUser, String confirmEmailTemplatePath, String pendingReviewEmailTemplatePath, String prescriptionVerificationPendingEmailTemplatePath, RxRenewalEmailPathBrandWise rxRenewalEmailPathDto, String renewalOnlyEmailTemlplate) in BusinessLogic\Services\Order\WebOrderService.cs:line 6347
   at Api.Controllers.Order.OrderController.ProcessWebOrder(WebOrderGroupDTO dto) in Api\Controllers\Order\OrderController.cs:line 812
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is my code:

```
public static void SetRecord(string recordId, string data, int minute = 30)
        {
            var redisConnection = Common.RedisCacheServiceClient();
            IDatabase dbConnection = redisConnection.GetDatabase();

            var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minute);
            dbConnection.StringSet(recordId, data, timeSpan);

        }
```

So the above code is implemented in class library which I am using in business-logic.
StackExchange.Redis version: = **2.1.58**
Microsoft.Bcl.Asyncinterfaces = **1.1.1**

My all projects are made on Microsoft.Bcl.Asyncinterfaces(**1.1.1**), so in order to make it compatible i used suitable stackexchange.redis version by using this website: [Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/2.1.58#dependencies-body-tab)

App.config of Redis class library:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I think it is because it is looking for version 6.0.0.0

Comment: And it is possible you also need the Microsoft.Bcl library too.